# How to store int values with same key

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a dictionary which is stored in JSON. But what I can't figure out is how to store the values with the same key.

For example:

Printing description of messages:

```
▿ Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>>   
▿ some : 1 element
     ▿ 0 : 2 elements
         - key : "messages"
         - value : 20
```

But I want it to be like this:

Printing description of messages:

```
▿ Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>>
▿ some : 1 element
   ▿ 0 : 2 elements
   - key : "messages"
      - value : 20
      - value : 22
      - value : 25
```

Is there a way to do this ?

This is what I did so far:

```
let idMessagesSelected = self.notifications[indexPath.row].id       
messagesSelected = ["messages": [idMessagesSelected]] as! [String : [Int]]           
let storedMessages = JSONStore.getSavedJSONData(forKey: "messages")

if !(storedMessages!.isEmpty) {
    messagesSelected.merge(storedMessages as! [String : [Int]]){(current, _) in current}
}

JSONStore.saveJSONWithData(data: messagesSelected, forKey: "messages")  

let messages = JSONStore.getSavedJSONData(forKey: "messages")
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You can save an array. In Swift, it'd be: `[String: [Int]]`. In JSON, `{ "message": [20, 22, 25] }`...

Comment: I tryed but it replaces the value everytime

Comment: It shouldn't. But the question is "how did you tried", because if you do it wrong, it won't work as expected...

Comment: Don’t post code in comments. Edit your post and add it there

Comment: sorry, i fixed it

Comment: You ideally should actually show what you expect your JSON to look like. A JSON object is effectively a dictionary. Any key can have only one associated value. Why do you need more than one value associated with a key? Or perhaps better phrased, describe what you are trying to solve that requires storing values with the same key.

Comment: Im trying to store the Id's Messages that the user has seen. 
It's for putting an image to a messenger, that's read or not. Depending on what messages have the user been reading

Comment: So you should use an array, see also the first comment.

Comment: and how can I combine two arrays like [String: [Int]] . ?

Comment: You could use `firstArray.append(contentsOf: secondArray)`